# Where to change encoding to print umlauts?

Tags: c#, encoding, default, diacritics

I'm looking around to fix this bug.
I have following code, but it always outputs words with false encoding.

```
    public static string sPart(string original)
    {
        string[] values = original.Split('\t');
        List<string> words = values.Skip(1).ToList();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            sb.Append(word + " ");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Does anyone know how to use another encoding?

Comment: The string which is used is `zts3e Großer Fuchs` .. but the code above returns `Gro?er Fuchs`

Comment: Okay I found the mistake. I didn't change the StreamReader Encoding. It was like being blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sPart("zts3e  Großer Fuchs"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string sPart(string original)
    {
        string[] values = original.Split('\t');
        List<string> words = values.Skip(1).ToList();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            sb.Append(word + " ");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

[image: Debug Image]

The code works.

How did you show the result of the method?

**EDIT**

There's actually a better way instead of using StringBuilder

```
public static string sPart(string original)
{
    return original.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
}
```